# Is there a way to include .launch files with a plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, launch

I am trying to create a plugin that will automatically generate an external tool when eclipse opens. I have looked into some options and it seems the best way to get it done is by loading a .launch file, with the information to create the external tool, into eclipse when the plugin is run. Up to now I have not been able to find a way to do this, does anyone know how it could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DebugUITools` to launch your .launch file. More information you can find in [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html) eclipse article.